# Adding array to non-rails model gives TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a model (`OrderFilter`) not tied to a database table which I use to pass filter parameters to the view.   The model and view are considerably more complicated than below but I've stripped it down to the bare essentials.

```
class OrderFilter  
  attr_accessor :role, :draft, :submitted, :approved, :processed, :errors  
  def initialize(user_id)
    # @errors = []
  end
end

# Controller
def index
  @order_filter = OrderFilter.new(session[:user_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end

# View:    
  <%= select(:order_filter, :role, ['a','b','c'] )%>
```

All worked as expected until I added an array to pass errors to the view (`@errors`).  Initialising the array in the constructor (ie. uncomment `# @errors = []`) produces `ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)` on the `select` tag line.

Any help would be appreciated - I've searched high and low and can't find anything similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that "errors" is used in rails to communicate validation specific errors from the model to the view. I guess the "select" tries to read those errors, and expects a different format... I guess simply by renaming the errors variable, your issue will be solved...

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple!  Thanks for the prompt response, Danny.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make your class more rails-friendly by including ActiveModel::Validations module. Which will handle all errors logic.